# Gradle Build fails [Android] 'META-INF/kotlinx-coroutines-core.kotlin_module'

Tags: android, gradle

Gradle did build my little adroid app fine.
After a while I added some more dependencies, it began to raise this error message and fails building.

Found similar problems, but all stated to exclude. Didnt help.
"
More than one file was found with OS independent path 'META-INF/kotlinx-coroutines-core.kotlin_module'
"
import looks like this
import kotlinx.coroutines.experimental.async

Gradle Build fiel looks like this
"

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

android {

    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/ASL2.0'
        //exclue  'META-INF/kotlinx-coroutines-core.kotlin_module'
    }
    compileSdkVersion 27
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.a18mas.app_mp3"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation"org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    /*_______________________NEW DEPENDENCIES______________________*/
    //local
    implementation files("/libs/ftp4j-1.7.2.jar", "/libs/kotlinx-coroutines-core-0.22.5.jar")

    //public
    implementation 'com.beust:klaxon:3.0.1'
    implementation 'com.github.kittinunf.fuel:fuel:+' //for JVM
    implementation 'com.github.kittinunf.fuel:fuel-android:+' //for Android
    implementation 'com.github.kittinunf.fuel:fuel-livedata:+' //for LiveData support
    implementation 'com.github.kittinunf.fuel:fuel-rxjava:+' //for RxJava support
    implementation 'com.github.kittinunf.fuel:fuel-coroutines:+' //for Kotlin Coroutines support
    implementation 'com.github.kittinunf.fuel:fuel-gson:+' //for Gson support
    implementation 'com.github.kittinunf.fuel:fuel-jackson:+' //for Jackson support
    implementation 'com.github.kittinunf.fuel:fuel-moshi:+' //for Moshi support
    implementation 'com.github.kittinunf.fuel:fuel-forge:+' //for Forge support

}
```

"

Answer (score 0):

You probably did this but ...

1. clean and build project
2. rebuild Gradle
3. restart IDE (this did the trick for me when I had weird gradle issues)
4. check all the version numbers of the dependencies

Comment: Appreciate your help. Unfortunnately building still fails. 

Source of the error should be this. However no idea why I get this error, nor how to solve it.
Program type already present: kotlinx.coroutines.experimental.AbstractContinuationKt
Message{kind=ERROR, text=Program type already present: kotlinx.coroutines.experimental.AbstractContinuationKt, sources=[Unknown source file], tool name=Optional.of(D8)}

Comment: Uups. Error was caused by two links to coroutines support.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with coroutines

```
implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:$kotlin_coroutine_version"
implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:$kotlin_coroutine_version"
```

I updated packagingOptions like this

```
packagingOptions {
    exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/ASL2.0'
    exclude 'META-INF/main.kotlin_module'
}
```

After it everything work correctly.